# apply a rotation relative to any reference space - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

is there a way to apply a rotation for any arbitrarily orientation (Object A's rotation relative to Object B's local orientation)
I know I can simply get desired result if i do setParent thing, but i want to get without it

In my situation, my character holds water bottle and moves around the room holding it so I set its rotation like this

`transform.rotation = mainCamera.transform.rotation;`

but As bottle top pointing to the sky seems more natural, I want it to rotate 90 degree by its own X-axis

I tried below codes but it dosent work as i intended

```
        `originalRotation = transform.rotation;
        Quaternion rotationDelta = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, mainCamera.transform.forward);
        transform.rotation = rotationDelta * originalRotation;`
```

Yes, Like i said above if i make my character parent to the bottle will solve the issue, but i want to
do it without it.

Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```cs
transform.forward = mainCamera.transform.up;
```